# How to create a chat screen similar to whatsapp in material design?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, material-design, whatsapp

Basically I am confused with the xml file for each chat entry with content wrapped like whatsapp. I have tried doing it using `framelayout` and `Relativelayout` but it didn't work. Message is not wrapped around the time.

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_mine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bg_white"
       >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_text_mine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="h"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chat_time_mine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                 android:gravity="right|bottom"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=" 2:00 am"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size4" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delivered" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to ask here ? If I understand it correct, edit you frame layout to show something first. This will help you see contents in ur preview.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_mine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_bg_white"
   >
```

Comment: the width should be wrap content, as in the chat bubble should wrap around the content

Comment: similar to the chat entry here  http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-WvBUQVdVnaU/U_DPUfLknyI/AAAAAAABcEY/GcF9A7MxZag/s1600/Screenshot_2014-08-13-16-23-16.png  , look at the time and delivered icon. I am not able mimic the same!!

Comment: anybody got the solution for this?